# what is the guidance automation and where do we use that...?

Tags: .net

what is the guidance automation and where do we use that.? Can anybody help me on what exactly it is and how we use this in our development activities?

Thanks,

sivaram.

Comment: Accept answers on your questions, so that more people will like to answer on your questions.

Comment: you have 16 unanswered questions, this is really too much

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a template or starter project for use by junior level developers. This post provides many good links:

http://www.luisrocha.net/2009/01/guidance-automation-toolkit-gat.html